# Laravel Route model binding (slug) only works for show method?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, slug

I have *Article* model and *articles* table in the database. Each article can be shown using Laravel's standard URI structure: `www.example.com/articles/5` (where `5` is the article `id`). Each article has a *slug* field (*slug* column in the articles table), so with **Route Model Binding** I use `slug` instead of `id`:

**RouteServiceProvider.php:**

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    \Route::bind('articles', function($slug) {
        return \App\Article::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

In routes.php I have:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
```

and now articles can be accessed with URLs like: `www.example.com/some_slug` .

But now, when I want to edit some article, I get the following error:

**No query results for model [App\Article].**

For example, when I try to open the following: `www.example.com/some_slug/edit` - I get that error.

So, method ArticleController@show(Article $article) works fine, but ArticleController@edit(Article $article) doesn't work.

Here is my route list:

[image: Rote List]

and here are *show* and edit methods from ArticleController:

```
public function show(Article $article)  // THIS WORKS FINE
{
    $tags = $article->tags()->get();
    return view('articles.show', compact('article', 'tags'));
}

public function edit(Article $article) // DOESN'T WORK -> When I open article/slug/edit I get error: No query results for model [App\Article].
{
    $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');
    $categories = Category::orderBy('lft', 'asc')->get()->lists('padded_name', 'id');
    return view('articles.edit', compact('article', 'tags', 'categories'));
}
```

Comment: you're missing the `s` at the end of your `edit` parameter. Should be `edit(Article $articles)`  not `edit(Article $article)` in order to match `/articles/{articles}`

Answer (score 15):

I believe in 5.2, you can customize the key name directly in the model using the `getRouteKeyName` method:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: The best and compact answer I guess. Every developer seems lazy(as me) to not read the entire document.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone wants to do route model binding with both `id` and `slug`, explicitly binding like this works:

```
// App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot

Route::bind('product', function($value) {
   return \App\Product::where('id', $value)->orWhere('slug', $value)->first();
});
```

Comment: This is great. Just adding that if you change `first()` to `firstOrFail()` at the end, it avoids the non-object error and throws a 404 instead.

Comment: After 2+ hours breaking my head... Thank you @swadhwa
Works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 7 and above, you can customize implicit route model bindings directly in the route definition.

```
Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', function (Post $post) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score -4):

I have another approach for you without touching RouteServiceProvider.php. I hope it helps.
You need **use App\Article;** and **use App\Tag;** in your ArticleController.
**ArticleController**

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');

        return view('articles.edit', compact('article', 'tags'));
    }

public function edit($slug)
    { 
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        $tags = Tag::lists('name', 'id');

        return view('articles.edit', compact('article', 'tags'));
    }
```